# String not recognized a timespan

Tags: c#, timespan

hope you could help me with this. Yesterday my code was working, but after I did some cleaning it stop working and it keeps on saying:

`String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan`

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = database.getSchedule();
        TimeSpan AMTime;
        TimeSpan PMTime;
        TimeSpan NNTime;
        TimeSpan _timeNow =  TimeSpan.Parse(timeNow);

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            AMTime = TimeSpan.Parse(row["AMIntake"].ToString());
            PMTime = TimeSpan.Parse(row["PMIntake"].ToString());
            NNTime = TimeSpan.Parse(row["NNIntake"].ToString());

            if (AMTime == _timeNow || PMTime == _timeNow || NNTime == _timeNow)
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("Drink Medicine");
            }
           else
            {
               /*do nothing*/
            }
```

Comment: Use a debugger and look what´s inside of `row["AMIntake"]`, we cannot guess what it is.

Comment: What is `timeNow` exactly or other strings in your foreach loop? On which line you get this?

Comment: it is the current time

Comment: `TimeSpan.Parse(row["AMIntake"].ToString())` - `ToString` and then back again `Parse` looks very *suspicious*. `AMTime = row["AMIntake"];`?

Comment: i get this from the database.

Comment: our system is comparing the time on the database and the current time

Comment: @SylviaEspiña Your comments don't give _any_ useful information to us so far. Please tell us which line you get this exception and what is your value looks like in the debugger that you try to parse.

Comment: @Sylvia Espiña , On which line you are getting the exception?

Comment: AMTime = TimeSpan.Parse(row["AMIntake"].ToString()); //on this line

Comment: @Sylvia Espiña , show us the output string from row["AMIntake"].ToString()

Comment: if it's from DB maybe you should be `ToString`ing and `Parse`ing with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`?